# How to call a generic method depending on new()

Tags: c#, generics, constraints

Something like this.

```
class C1<T> : I1<T> where T:class{ 
  void M1() {}
}
class C2<T> : I1<T> where T:class,new(){
  void M2() {}
  void irrelevant_method{ ... new T(); ... }
}
class C3<T> where T:class {
  void M3(I1<T> x){
    // how to call M1 or M2?
    if (x is C1<T>) (x as C1<T>).M1();
    else if (x is C2<T>) (x as C2<T>).M2(); // error
  }
}
```

It doesn't compile -- we know something the compiler does not. If `x` is a `C2` we know it has the `new()` constraint but we can't 'promote' x because C3 does not have `new()` itself.

And no, I cannot just add new(). I really do have to deal with classes that have no default ctor.

Any ideas?

---

Edit: added irrelevant method which uses new T(), but has nothing to do with the question.

---

Although the question is *not* a duplicate, turns out the answer is the same. Get rid of the `new()` constraint and use `Activator.CreateInstance<T>()` at runtime. Thanks for the link.

Comment: Does reflection can be an option for you ?

Comment: I see no constructor calls on `T` in that code: I think that's a red herring. What *exactly* is the error message you are getting. Also put the content of the ifs on separate lines so you can distinguish errors from the predicate and controlled statement clearly.

Comment: Worth pointing out that the `x is C2<T>` is the first error. No easy way around this, you would need a 2nd, constrained, T2 and that makes using it a mess. Bette answer: refactor C3 into two specialized classes.

Comment: @HenkHolterman `T : class` and `T : class, new()` are 2 different types for the compilator ? It's just frustrating if we cannot use `T : class, new()` in simple `T : class` because for human they are the same type, just the first one can instanciate new objects... Do you know why `where T : class` cannot encapsulate `where T : class, new()` ?

Comment: @Richard: added irrelevant method (see edit). The error is the usual one about T needing a class with a default ctor.

Comment: @HenkHolterman: yes, that is the compile error, you nailed that one. And C1 has to work with classes that don't provide new(). So what do you suggest?

Comment: If the method has the `new()` constraint, then the type _must_ meet the constraint. There's no "well, okay...it's against the rules, but just this once" feature in C#. You can create instances without the `new()` constraint, as in the marked duplicate.

Answer (score -1):

May be you should use somethink like this:

```
interface I1<T>
    {
        void Some ();
    }

    class C1<T> : I1<T> where T:class{ 
        public void M1() {}

        public void Some()
        {
        }
    }
    class C2<T> : I1<T> where T:class{
        public void M2() {}
        public void Some()
        {
        }
    }
    class C3<T> where T:class {
        void M3(I1<T> x){
            if (x is C1<T>) (x as C1<T>).M1();
            else if (x is C2<T>) (x as C2<T>).M2();
        }

        public void Some()
        {
        }
    }
```

Comment: You're example is correct but i think the question is about the mix of `T:class` and `T:class, new()`

Comment: @mixim: how can that help? You just removed the new() constraint.